# RailsTutorial.org Chapter 1 - error on first server run: Rack::Lint::LintError at / env missing required key SERVER_NAME

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm going through the new 3rd edition of Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I'm receiving this error whenever i run the webserver and request the home page in [section 1.3.2](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-rails_server):

```
Rack::Lint::LintError at /
env missing required key SERVER_NAME

Ruby    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb: in assert, line 20
Web GET rails-tutorial-c9-ryderstorm_1.c9.io/
```

I'm using cloud9 and all I've done at this point is install the server with `rails new`, switch to the newly create app directory, update the gemfile,  and run `bundle install`. I've tried deleting the app directory and repeating the tutorial steps but I get the same issue.

I went through section 5 of the tutorial in 2nd edition a couple months ago and never saw this error. Google searching for the error doesn't come up with anything useful for a Rails novice, either. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I had the same exact experience.  I'm sure it's a bug in the cloud9 setup.  I installed all of the software locally on my ubuntu 14.04 box and was able to run that part without problems.

Comment: I know this is a Rails question but if you run into this issue with Sinatra add `--server webrick` to your start command. Like this: `rackup --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --server webrick --env development`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the hostname that Cloud9 uses. Cloud9 allows underscores in the subdomain names while rails/rack can't deal with those. If your workspace name is for example `rails_tutorial` then you will see this error. In this case the easy fix would be to create a new workspace and use e.g. `rails-tutorial` instead.

Update:

Cloud9 has rolled out an update, which makes sure that the subdomains never contain any underscores so the issue should be solved for good.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I had run into this earlier on another Cloud9 workspace months ago but had forgotten about the underscore issue. Its up and running now, thank you!

Comment: Hi Fabian, this didn't work for me.  I tried changing the workspace name, the app name, and none of these things worked.  I still keep getting the same problem.  Any additional insight or help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I just read my gmail account for the explanation, username on account can't have an underscore.  I don't use the gmail account much, due to historical reasons.  I've deleted the old Cloud9 account and created one without an underscore in my username, which makes everthing work.